# Combining same-file Excel sheets with missing headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas, how can I read all sheets from an excel file into a single dataframe, where the first sheet has a header, but the other sheets do not? (As shown below)

[image: the first sheet]

[image: the others]

My code is as follows, is there a simpler way?

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xls', header=None, sheet_name=None)
df1 = pd.concat(df).reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0,:]
```

Comment: Read in the file that doesn't have column names then assign them with `names=` like `pd.read_excel(filename, names=["id", "NAME"])`

Comment: You can then combine your dataframes with `pd.concat` like: `pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I think your way is actually really good, only thing I'd change is `pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)` instead of `reset_index...` Don't forget to drop the first row, and convert `id` to integer instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, there isn't a specifically good method I know of to do this.

```py
dfs = pd.read_excel('filename.xls', header=None, sheet_name=None)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
df = df.drop(0) # Now you can reset_index if you want.
df.id = df.id.astype(int)
```

Output:

```
       id   Name
1  100039  Grace
2  100040  Kathy
3   97975  Kevin
4   97976  Denny
5   97977  Henry
```